# How to Convert python Tkinter desktop App to Web App

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have wrote python (2.7) GUI desktop application using TKinter library and it is working fine. Now I want to convert it into web application. I have looked into pyjaco and pyjamas but not getting it done.

How can I convert it into Web App?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to rewrite your app. There is simply no way to convert a tkinter application to run on the web. You could potentially use pyjs to convert some of the business logic, but the entire GUI will have to be rewritten.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [CloudTk](http://cloudtk.tcl-lang.org/).

> CloudTk is based on WebSockit2me - a TCP to WebSocket gateway that uses a noVNC to display Tk applications in modern Web Browser.

Comment: Are you aware of any modern guides or examples with CloudTk? I have not had any luck getting it going.