# Convert tkinter program into web application

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, web-applications

I'm working on a genetic algorithm project that involves manipulating and evolving 3D shapes. So far, the entire project has been completed in tkinter, with the selection, evolution, and saving of shapes all working as intended. The program starts by asking for a username in the console, after which the gui takes over.

My problem is I would like the general public to have access to this. It would greatly increase the diversity of the shapes that can be used in the evolutionary process, and the rest of my family admittedly doesn't know how to run a python script so I can't just send them my code. Is there a way to host a tkinter application online? What's the best way to do that?

If not, what would an alternative be and how could I learn the system? I'm extremely passionate about this and just want to do the absolute best job I can with it. Any help is appreciated!!

Cheers

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57078952/13629335)

Comment: @Thingamabobs Thanks that helps a ton, I'll look into Flask/Django and how to show 3D plots on the web

Answer (score 1):

You can use CloudTk.

```
CloudTk is a TCP to WebSocket gateway that uses a noVNC to display Tk (or X11) applications in modern Web Browser.
```

https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/CloudTk

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31327136)